# How to migrate to the models from a previous commit?

Tags: django, git, branch, django-migrations

I have a python Django project with several applications and multiple git branches for each features.

It's a true hell to do the migration by hand because there are too many apps, and have to diff `showmigrations` to see what have changed...

Is there a way to automate this, or at least a way to generate the migration I should restore the db to ?

Comment: The question comes back regularly: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+branches+Django+migrations

Comment: My advice is not (un)apply migrations back and forth but to have a separate worktree + a separate DB for every branch.

Comment: well, here it's a docker, and I'm running out of free space...